# Entity Framework 6.0 auto-generates classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 database first in an MVC 5 Project. I know that model validation is suppose to be done with validation attributes inside the entity classes. However, every time I make a change to my edmx model it regenerates my entity classes and I lose all of my validation attributes. Should I just do Model Validation in my Controller classes or is there a way to stop the entity framework from regenerating my entity classes.

Comment: Generated classes are partial. Create another class with the same name and in the same namespace but in different folder. And extend it instead.

Comment: Generally the advice is to use a view model class which you map to your actual persisted Entity class. The view model is likely to be a subset of the Entity members which are those to either be displayed or received from the user in that particular context. Validation attributes can then be added to the view model. Another advantage of the view model is it makes it harder for a malicious user to manipulate internal properties of your entity through a carefully crafted POST request as the property isn't present in the view model for the MVC model binder to bind to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Metadata class with the validations etc and attach it to the model using a partial class with a `MetadataType` annotation. Here's a very simple example of how to do this:

```
//assume this is the model Entity Framework autogenerates
public partial class SomeClass {
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

//everything under this is what you need to add (in a new file, don't edit generated code)
public class SomeClassMetadata {

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Enter a foo here:")]
    public string Foo { get; set; }

}

[MetadataType(typeof(SomeClassMetadata))]
public partial class SomeClass {
}
```